# Full effects of being in the same team in Civilization V

Tags: civilization-5

When two civilizations are in the same team in Civilization V, they share research and diplomacy apart from City State alliances, but have separate social policies, separate treasuries, separate tourism, etc.

Overall it seems that teamed players are considered separate civilizations in some matters and the same civilization in others. What are the complete effects of being in the same team?

Comment: Spaceship parts are shared, or at least were shared at some point. You still need to move all parts to the same city to get the thing to launch though. It also counts only one player(the host) for getting the multiplayer win achievement IIRC. But it's been a long time ago, and my memory might be faulty, or stuff might have changed with the last expansion.

Comment: @Arperum Thanks a lot, spaceship parts are important. If anyone could provide a complete list as an answer, I would be overjoyed.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [GameFaqs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/938528-sid-meiers-civilization-v/56669835) discussing this, here is a list one of the users there compiled:

- When any player on the team researches the tech tree all of the teammates get the technology.
  If you both research the same tech at the same time, the time for completing it will be halved.
- You also see the map under fog of war which is cleared by the other player on the team.
- If any player on the team declares war on someone, the whole team goes into the war.
- Also, the the points of everyone in the team will be counted together and it shows a team score at the list on the right.
- You can gift units (both combat & civilian) to your teammates just like you can for city-states normally.
- However you won't automatically share luxory- & strategic resources, but the standard trading mechanics work as normal so you can trade half of what you have over to your teammate for example.

  - You have permanent Declaration of Friendship with each other
  - You'll still feel ideological pressure (reduced happiness for adopting different ideologies) from team mates
  - Autocracy tenet Futurism doesn't work against team mates.

As he mentions himself, there is probably more.

Comment: Thanks, but I won't accept since I specifically asked for a full list and this is a very meager one.

Comment: @kviiri Feel free to add to it, we have an edit function you know ;)

Comment: I would've answered it myself if I knew the full list of effects. But I guess I might have to do some research on this myself eventually...

Comment: How does tourism and a cultural victory work for a team?

Comment: I've never tried Cultural victory as a team, but the Autocracy tenet Futurism doesn't work against team mates